# Best way to structure a sync between a tablet and a database?

Tags: android, synchronization

Just curious on the best practice on syncing data from a database to an android tablet.

Tables:

```
- Part1
- Part2
- Part3
- Part4
- Part5
```

Whenever I open the app on the tablet I grab the latest lists from the database, truncate the table, and re-add the records. Each table consists of 400 records. So it takes around 60.45 per table to grab the data from the server and add it. Since I have 5 tables it takes around 5 minutes. Is there a better way to achieve efficient syncing for what I am doing? After I grab the data from the server, instead of truncating the table I've tried checking if it exists firsts before adding it but that didn't help with the time.

What I am currently doing: I get the JSON list from the API server and truncate the table and add the rows back. Pretty time consuming with 5 tables of 500 records each.

```
    libraryApp = (LibraryApp) act.getApplication();
    List<Pair> technicians = getJsonData("get_technicians");
    if(technicians.size() > 0) {
        stiLibraryApp.getDataManager().emptyTechnicianTable(); // truncate current table
        // add technicians back to database
        for(Pair p : technicians) {
            libraryApp.getDataManager().saveTechnician(new Technician((Integer) p.key(), (String) p.value()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question based on some snippet of code? Its hard to answer a "best way" question with no idea of what you're doing.

Comment: I am trying to sync data from a remote database to a tablet so that people can use it while being mobile. I want the app to sync two ways: 1) when you first open the app it will grab all the data initially 2) a button called 'sync' which will update/re-add the data from the database if it has changed. Is that better?

Comment: How are you doing it now? What have you tried? Can you show the code?

Comment: @Rarw Posted. I'm just trying to find out if theres a better way to sync rather than TRUNCATE and re-INSERT

Answer (score 0):

Given the limited information provided I would try the following:

(1) Have your server keep a record of when the table you are updating was last "put" on the server. I have no idea what backend language you are using so I cannot make a sugestion. But it should be really easy to keep a lastupdated timestamp.

With this timestamp you will be able to tell if the version of the table on your server is more recent than the version on your mobile device.

(2) Using an `AsyncTask` download the data you need. I am not sure if all 5 tables are in the same activity, in seperate activities, in fragments or something else. However, the general idea is as follows:

```
private class GetTableData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(){
        //get data from your sever
        return null;
    }


    protect void onPostExecute(Void result){
        //update the table view if version on server is newer
    }
```

You will place all your I/O methods, that is those that connect to your server and download data within `doInBackground`. You will place all methods that update the table view within `onPostExecute`. This seperation is necessary because while I/O functions must run in the background after Jellybean, views must be updated from the UI thread.

(3) Check the timestamp of what you downloaded. If what you downloaded is newer update your table. You can acomplish this by simply adding in a conditional statment to your `onPostExecute` function such that

```
if(lastDownloadTime < lastUpdatedOnServerTime){
    //update view
}
```

Depending on how big the table files are you may want to add a function on your sever code that just returns the time the table was last updated. That way you can check the time it was last updated against the time you last downloaded the table. If the table was updated on the server after you downladed it you can proceed to download the new information.

That's the basic idea. You can adapt it to your own set up.

Comment: But your answer has nothing to do with sync behavior and efficiency? I already check if I need to sync with latest data but my issue is how can I improve the speed after I check if(lastDownloadTime < lastUpdatedOnServerTime){? Because I download the lists but then it takes forever to add the data to the database

Comment: What are you adding that it takes so long to upload? The fastest way would be to only download and post those fields which have been changed. To do that you would need to track the lastupdated time for each editable value of the table. If your table is indexed, its easy to only replace the values that have been modified since they are all keyed.